# Google Rich Result Testing Tool Error: Parsing error: Missing ‘}’ or object member name

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js, google-search

My website: [www.bharatpharmatech.com](http://www.bharatpharmatech.com)
My code is in nextjs
My Schema Is:

`{ "@context": "https://schema.org/", "@type": "WebSite", "name": "Bharat Pharmatech", "url": "https://bharatpharmatech.com", "potentialAction": { "@type": "SearchAction", "target": "https://bharatpharmatech.com/search/{search_term_string}", "query-input": "required name=search_term_string" } }`
Note: I have did not added any extra commas

I don't know why google converting "(double quote) to "
Google Schema Markup Tool Parsing:
`{&quot;@context&quot;:&quot;https://schema.org&quot;,&quot;@type&quot;:&quot;Corporation&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Bharat Pharmatech&quot;,&quot;alternateName&quot;:&quot;Pharma Machinery &amp; Spares&quot;,&quot;url&quot;:&quot;https://bharatpharmatech.com&quot;,&quot;logo&quot;:&quot;https://res.cloudinary.com/dzainnrtc/image/upload/v1677398892/apple-touch-icon_cvh6w8.png&quot;,&quot;contactPoint&quot;:[{&quot;@type&quot;:&quot;ContactPoint&quot;,&quot;telephone&quot;:&quot;9687849837&quot;,&quot;contactType&quot;:&quot;customer service&quot;,&quot;contactOption&quot;:&quot;TollFree&quot;,&quot;areaServed&quot;:&quot;IN&quot;,&quot;availableLanguage&quot;:[&quot;en&quot;,&quot;Hindi&quot;,&quot;Marathi&quot;,&quot;Gujarati&quot;]},{&quot;@type&quot;:&quot;ContactPoint&quot;,&quot;telephone&quot;:&quot;0901507751&quot;,&quot;contactType&quot;:&quot;technical support&quot;,&quot;contactOption&quot;:&quot;TollFree&quot;,&quot;areaServed&quot;:&quot;IN&quot;,&quot;availableLanguage&quot;:[&quot;en&quot;,&quot;Hindi&quot;,&quot;Marathi&quot;,&quot;Gujarati&quot;]}],&quot;sameAs&quot;:[&quot;www.bharatpharmatech.com&quot;,&quot;https://youtube.com/@pharmamachineryspares&quot;,&quot;https://instagram.com/bharatpharmatech&quot;]}`

I have tried to changing my code but do not worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at your source code page not in inspect mode on you browser because quote are interpreted.

```
curl https://bharatpharmatech.com/
```

Or with option view source on your browser

It seems to be your nextjs output which generate the quote escaping

Comment: Thank you i have checked by your reference and it worked

Comment: @jules-sarraute
In the case of escaped quotes, will google still process structured data correctly?
(While the rich results test shows this error)

Comment: @Nomirimon I don't know but you can test it here https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data